# How do you output multiple .js files to dist/ folder in angular 6 angular.json

Tags: angular6

In your angular.json, how would you output multiple .js files into your dist/ folder after running ng build.  Seems like it would make sense to do something like:

```
"outputPath": "dist/",
"index": "src/index.html",
"main": "src/main.ts”,
"something": "src/something/main.ts”,
"somethingElse": "src/somethingElse/main.ts",...
```

I end up with an error:

```
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(something)
```

I would like my dist/ folder to have:

```
main.js
something.js
somethingElse.js
```

Can someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I actually needed was to create multiple applications within one workspace.

Taken from the angular-cli wiki:

`ng generate application my-other-app`

The new application will be generated inside 
`projects/my-other-app`

Now we can serve, build etc. both the apps by passing the project name with the commands:

`ng serve my-other-app`

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects

Hopefully this will help someone if they ever run across this problem.